# GKPeerPickerController Gives "wait_fences" Error When Using cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit, gkpeerpickercontroller

I have a cocos2d game all set up with a root view controller as it is meant to be. However, I am implementing Bluetooth gameplay, and when the user presses the cancel button on the peer picker controller, there is about 2 seconds of lag, and I get "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003" printed in the console. How can I fix this behaviour?

EDIT: `-peerPickerControllerDidCancel:` contents:

```
- (void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel:(GKPeerPickerController *)aPicker {
    aPicker.delegate = nil;
    [aPicker autorelease];
}
```

Thanks,
jrtc27

Comment: What does your implementation for peerPickerControllerDidCancel: look like?

Comment: I tried it out and yeah, even the simplest possible wait_fences of GKPeerPickerController straight out from the Apple Documentation does this. Curiously, the sample GKTank app also suffers from the same problem. Afraid I have no idea why, sorry. Doesn't seem to have any negative effect though?

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it, as it seems there is no answer. Probably something to do with using OpenGL to render the game...